# How to connect a C # system with a MySQL database outside the LAN?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know how to connect the client pc in a outside network for example a WAM network, i have my database in my pc and i use this like the server. I know how to connect mysql with another client computer inside the LAN network but i dont know how to do it like the other way.
if you don't understand something make me know.
PD: sorry for my english is my first question on a english forum

Comment: Set-up port-forwarding or create a VPN.

Comment: This is not a c# or mysql question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately it works exactly the same way - you need an IP address and a port to connect to your database on.  You can either do this by setting up port-forwarding at the firewall on the network with the database server (basically, forward port 3306 to the LAN IP address), or by giving the database server a publicly available static IP and then opening port 3306 in any firewalls.  Alternatively, you can set up a VPN to the network with the database server, and connect through this.  If done right, the VPN option is much more secure.

However, you should ask yourself why you want to do this.  Is your idea to have a client software that directly connects to the database?  This is not a great design - it's usually better to have a backend database that is accessed via a frontend API (e.g. a RESTful API or similar).  Among other benefits, this can give you much better (finer-grained) access control to the database.

Answer (score -1):

Your MySql server should have a firewall rule to accept outside connection on MySql port (default is 3306). Best setup should allow connection from your clients WAN address only.

Then, your C# connector will be able to connect just the same as in LAN.